# How to get the width of the entire webpage, not just window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I understand that we could get the width of the window by using

```
$(window).width();
```

However, that is only the width of the window excluding the overflowing portion. What I mean by overflowing is that the element exceeds the current window viewport width and you need to use the bottom scroll bar to scroll it left and right.

one would suggest to get the width of that particular overflowing div. But what if I somehow unable to get the width of this div (be it dynamically generated or what not)

Is there a way to find the maximum width of the entire WEBPAGE with overflowing elements?

Thanks!

Comment: `$(document).width()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this -

```
$(document).width();
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the width of the element which exceeds the width of window instead of window.

**For tags:**

```
$('tag').width();
```

**For an element with class name:**

```
$('.class').width();
```

**For an element with id name:**

```
$('#id').width();
```